# Integration of JavaScript and JMS

Tags: java, javascript, jms, ejb, activemq-classic

Where can I find a guide for integrating JavaScript and JMS (Java Messaging Service)?

I would like a best practice or established technology that allows me to directly or indirectly receive messages from a topic and update a site based on the message. I was thinking of creating two components, a servlet for the Web module, and an MDB (Message-Driven Bean) for the EJB module. The web client will comsume messages from the JMS topic, and the MDB will handle the onMessage.

Does this sound correct? Have you seen any examples?

Edit: I am using ActiveMQ for the JMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [this](http://activemq.apache.org/ajax.html) is your answer.  Looks like it is baked in to ActiveMQ.  I tried the examples and they seem to work.

http://activemq.apache.org/ajax.html

Comment: I was able to get the examples to work on Version 5.0 of ActiveMQ. However they have trouble running in 5.1. Which version of ActiveMQ are you running?

Comment: We did have a lot of problems with this servlet, and we did abandon it completely...

Comment: i used the examples; i was able to send messages to the Q, but could not consume them :(

Answer (score 1):

I would try using [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/) to integrate JavaScript with your Java app. It makes Java to JavaScript communication transparent and only requires one servlet + configuration of what to expose. I haven´t done this with JMS, but it should work the same. There are three technologies that together solve all my integration problems, [Spring](http://springframework.org), [Mule](http://mulesource.org), and DWR.

Comment: I'll second DWR - excellent (and painless!) to integrate any server-side based Java and JavaScript on the client front-end

Answer (score 0):

You'll find some references to the Dojo/Bayeux approach here
http://www.pathf.com/blogs/2006/08/bayeux_a_json_p/

If you're using WebSphere 6.0 or higher then the Web 2.0 Feature Pack includes an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The [Seam framework](http://www.seamframework.org/) supports subscription to JMS topics from a JavaScript based client:

http://docs.jboss.com/seam/2.0.2.GA/reference/en-US/html/remoting.html#d0e14169