# Need help in creating Java Script to put/publish sample xml on JMS queue

Tags: java, xml, jms, jndi

I am new to javaScript or JMS queues, all I needs is a script which will put the sample xml on to the JMS queue with below property details.

We have different queues for different XML msgs. Need utility to publish test data into the desired JMS queue (which can be configured in the JMS property file)

**I have below JMS properties:**

```
jms.receiveTimeout=1000
username=ABC
password=
jndi.url=abcd01.ute.test.com:48120
jndi.initialContextFactory=com.test.mi.decorator.jms.testTibcoInitialContext
jms.producerName=TEST.TESTMANIFEST.ABC.L1
directConnection=true
```

**Sample XMl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TESTDataEvent>
   <TESTRecord>
      <TESTclientDetail>
         <TESTaccountNumber>450586162</TESTaccountNumber>
         <TESTNumber>6504535</TESTNumber>
         <TESTmeterNumber>0251901</TESTmeterNumber>
         <TESTsoftwareId>XYZ</TESTsoftwareId>
         <TESTsoftwareRelease>3105</TESTsoftwareRelease>
         <TESTclientProductId>PQR</TESTclientProductId>
      </TESTclientDetail>
   </TESTRecord>
</TESTDataEvent>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integration of JavaScript and JMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66840/integration-of-javascript-and-jms)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Integration of Javascript and JMS talks about ActiveMQ for the JMS. I am just trying to make simple Java script which can publish the data onto desired queue. I may not understand the purpose of ActiveMQ for the JMS beinf newbie, just trying to create simple tool.